# No Scratch Org Definition Configuration Value For Contacts to Multiple Accounts

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

There is currently no way to enable "Contacts to Multiple Accounts" in the scratch org configuration file: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Our repository/dx project includes the AccountContactRelation object and references it in layouts which means that this setting must be **manually** enable for every new scratch org before the source can be pushed to the scratch org. **Because of this , we are not able to setup or CI pipeline to create temporary scratch orgs for testing.**

Are there any workarounds for this? Also, is access to this setting in the config file planned to be released anytime soon?

Comment: Not that someone *won't* be able to answer this here, but the Salesforce DX team has a group on the Trailblazer Community where they're very active and often able to help with this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

It is now available.